# iPad - modal view - UINavigationController title is jumping

Tags: ipad, modalviewcontroller

So I'm presenting a UINavigationController as a standard modal window on the iPad (`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`). And I'm setting the title of it inside the root view controller.

When it slides up the title is on the left side (as if it would be center if the width was the 320 of the iPhone), and then when it stops the title jumps to the true middle.

Any idea why this is / what I can do about it?